# Pipe Screen to PHP (or any function for that matter)

Tags: php, linux, unix, pipe, gnu-screen

I'm looking for a way to pipe the output of the *nix `screen` command to another program. In theory I would like to be able to do something like:
`screen -S test | php testscript.php` and testscript.php receive it through `php://stdin`
However I am open to other options if necessary.

Comment: Screen opens up a virtual terminal, it's not actually running anything, so there is nothing to pipe into the php script. If you did screen -S test then typed a command like `cat some.log | php test script.php` that would work. Why are you using screen? Can't you just push the process into the background using &?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$fd = fopen("php://stdin","r");
$foo = "";
while ( !feof($fd) ){
    $foo .= fread($fd,1024);
}


fclose($fd);

//rest of script
```

command line: screen -S test |/path/to/php/script.php
makes user script file is chmod to 755

Comment: I tried that, however I did not receive the contents of the screen.

Comment: can you pipe screen to a file?

Comment: Simply put not really. `screen -S test > output.txt` returns nothing, no matter the contents of the screen. However `screen -S test -L` makes a text file called screenlog.n

Comment: well if you cant pipe it to a txt file you cant pipe it to anything else

Comment: looking at what screen does, im not surprised at the results, what is it your actully trying to achieve?